# How can I extend /dev/sda6 – is it possible?

Tags: centos, partition, lvm, fdisk

I need to extend `/dev/sda6` on other occasions and used the following guide (https://www.miarec.com/doc/administration-guide/doc1012), adding a new disk to the VM, but apparently it is not compatible with this case, since the fs I am trying to extend does not correspond to an LVM. Also these do not have a VG name since when executing `vgdisplay` I do not get results. I have the possibility to take a snapshot to the machine so I have tried several ways but without success. Sorry if I did not pose the question in the correct way.

```
[root@runner003 ~]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 150.3 GB, 150323855360 bytes, 293601280 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000cf166

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200   211814399   104857600   83  Linux
/dev/sda3       211814400   253757439    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       253757440   293601279    19921920    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       253759488   270276607     8258560   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       270278656   280764415     5242880   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       280766464   293601279     6417408   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.7 GB, 15728640000 bytes, 30720000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x22061e6d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    30719999    15358976   8e  Linux LVM
[root@runner003 ~]# lvmdiskscan
  /dev/sda1 [       1.00 GiB] 
  /dev/sda2 [     100.00 GiB] 
  /dev/sda3 [      20.00 GiB] 
  /dev/sda5 [      <7.88 GiB] 
  /dev/sda6 [       5.00 GiB] 
  /dev/sda7 [       6.12 GiB] 
  /dev/sdb1 [     <14.65 GiB] LVM physical volume
  0 disks
  6 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  1 LVM physical volume
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `/dev/sda[1-7]` are not LVM logical volumes, but plain traditional disk partitions.

Each partition must always be a single group of consecutive disk blocks on a single disk. Extending a partition is only possible at its tail end: if a partition occupies blocks X..Y, you could extend it to cover blocks X..(Y+N) - but only if blocks (Y+1)..(Y+N) are all free.

In your case, `sda6` ends at block #280764415 and `sda7` begins at block #280766464. And `sda7` seems to continue all the way to the end of the disk. So without first deleting or shrinking `sda7`, you can only extend `sda6` by (280766464 - 1) - 280764415 = 2048 blocks, or in other words, by exactly 1 MiB. That's so little it's not worth the trouble in most cases.

If you were to shrink `sda7`, shrinking a partition also happens at its tail end. So after shrinking the partition, you would have to also *move* it towards the tail end of the disk. Moving a partition requires unmounting it, and as the move is a write-intensive operation, it is going to take a while... so it will require some application downtime.

If `sda6` is not your root filesystem, I would urge you to instead:

1. add a new disk to the VM,
2. prepare it as a LVM physical volume (`pvcreate`),
3. add it to the same LVM volume group as your `sdb1` disk may already be in using `vgextend`(unless you know you will need to move `sdb1` to a different computer/VM separately from the new disk later, in which case create a new volume group for the new disk with `vgcreate`),
4. create a LVM logical volume on it (`lvcreate`),
5. `mkfs` the logical volume using your preferred filesystem type,
6. mount it to some temporary location,
7. copy the contents of `sda6` to it (`cp -a` as root works well in most cases),
8. unmount `sda6` and mount your new LVM logical volume to the same mountpoint `sda6` occupied previously. Edit `/etc/fstab` so that your new LVM logical volume will automatically get mounted into `sda6`'s previous location at every reboot from now.

Once you've confirmed that you've copied everything successfully, you can then make `sda6` into another LVM physical volume, and then use it to further extend your LVM volume group (with `vgextend`). That will allow you to use the space to later extend any existing logical volumes in the same volume group (`lvextend`), or to create one or more new logical volumes (`lvcreate`) if needed.

If `sda6` contains your root filesystem (`/`), then moving it onto LVM is possible but quite tricky; I would recommend instead creating a new VM and choosing to make a LVM-based installation in the OS installer this time. After making a LVM-based installation of the base OS, you could install all the same software packages as in the old VM, copy over all the users, groups and all the non-OS files, and finally retire the old VM.

Comment: Quite possibly simply adding another virtual disk and correct mount points will be enough if just some dirs require more space